# How to run only smoke test cases suite in jenkins?

Tags: selenium, jenkins

I have smoke,regression test cases and i need to create a job to run only smoke test cases and another job to run only regression test cases.

How can i create a job in Jenkins to run only smoke test cases?

I am using TestNg framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define test suites which contains those 100 tests - for example in testng

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name = "Suite1">
   <test name = "exampletest2">
      <classes>
         <class name = "Test2" />
      </classes>
   </test>
</suite>
```

Then simply run this suite in jenkins jobs